# (Neo4j) Carry variable over subsequent queries

Tags: variables, neo4j, pipe, with-statement

I am trying to carry over a variable through 2 subsequent queries. It seems like WITH only helps carry over the variable to the next query, but not any before that. Suggestions?

This is example of what I am trying to do:
***Person nodes** contain information on publishers, writers and editors (e.g. name, gender, etc.)

**Story nodes** contain data on Story (e.g. title, publish date, etc.)

**IN relationships** have categories: created, edited, published*.

Return editor-publishers who have edited stories published by another editor-publisher:
*assume no duplicate Person names*

1. Find all Persons who have edited at least one story who have also published at least one story
2. Find list of stories published by these editor-publishers in 1
3. In all editors of stories in 2, return sublist of these editors also in 1

```
MATCH (EditorPublisher:Person)-[:IN{category: "published"}]->(:Story)   // 1
WHERE (EditorPublisher:Person)-[:IN{category: "edited"}]->(:Story)
WITH COLLECT(EditorPublisher.name) as EditorPublisher_list
 
MATCH (EditorPublisher_stories:Story)<-[:IN{category: "published"}]-(publisher:Person) // 2
WHERE publisher.name in EditorPublisher_list
WITH EditorPublisher_list            // throws error EditorPublisher_list variable not found
WITH COLLECT(EditorPublisher_stories.title) as EditorPublisher_stories_list
  
MATCH (epe:Person)-[contribution:PLAYED]-(eps:Movie) // 3
WHERE epe.name in EditorPublisher_list
    AND eps IN EditorPublisher_stories_list
RETURN epe.name
```

Comment: Maybe save the results to file and post-process?

Comment: 1. Your first 2 queries are not complete queries (they don't return anything). 2. Why can't you combine all 3 queries into a single query? 3. If they remain separate queries, then is it possible that the intermediate results could get stale, causing 1 or 2 of your last 2 queries to not return accurate and complete results?

Answer (score 1):

NVM I got it to work. With does keep the variables if i don't rename them.

I just had to do WITH return.nodes, and call the return.nodes in subsequent queries instead of using in [return.nodes.list]